# Generalizing Odom's construction of the golden ratio

Tags: geometry, polygons, golden-ratio

The artist and amateur mathematician [George Odom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Phillips_Odom_Jr.) found this nice construction for the *golden ratio* $\phi$ using an *equilateral* triangle and its *circumcircle*,

$\hskip2.3in$[image]
$\hskip3.3in$**Fig. 1**

Let $A$ and $B$ be the midpoints. The ratio of the line segments $|AB|$ and $|BC|$ is, 
$$R_3 = \frac{|AB|}{|BC|} =\phi$$

---

We can easily generalize the above figure using a *square*,

$\hskip2.3in$[image]
$\hskip3.3in$**Fig. 2**

Let the (sadly invisible) $A,B,C$ of Fig.2 be analogous to that of Fig.1. What is then its,

$$R_4=\frac{|AB|}{|BC|} =\,?$$

> **Q:** In general, is $R_n$ for $n>3$ algebraic? If it is, does its minimal polynomial have a closed-form?

Comment: I haven’t got the time to work this out, unfortunately, but have you tried metallic ratios?

Comment: @giobrach: Geometry is not my strong suit, so I will have to wait until someone with expertise comes across this question.

Comment: In the meantime, take a look at this Desmos simulation of the problem for general $n$ that I made: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/flhcoj9nzy

Comment: Also, my conjecture is that $R_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 2 + 2\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @giobrach: Thanks. It seems for $n=3,4,5,6,7,8$ we have $$-1 - r + r^2 = 
  0\\ - 2 - 2 r + r^2 = 
    0\\1 + 2 r - 2 r^2 - 3 r^3 + r^4 = 
      0\\ - 3 - 3 r + r^2 = 
        0\\ - 1 - 4 r - 3 r^2 + r^3 = 0\\2 + 4 r - 2 r^2 - 4 r^3 + r^4 = 0$$ I recognize the case $n=7$, but not the others. Hm.

Comment: I worked on a problem that involved similar polynomials arising from Beraha constants a while ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282976/crazy-patterns-arising-from-recursive-sequence-of-functions
What I'm guessing is those minimal polynomials are lacking factors that would make them more recognizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From purely trigonometric considerations (see [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/whddil7l87) Desmos simulation, or ask if you need clarifications), I've found a closed form for your sequence:
$$R_n =  \frac{\sin\left(\frac {2\pi}{n}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)}{2}\right)^2}-\frac 1 2\sin\left(\frac {2\pi}{n}\right)}$$

It does not look pretty, but I'm sure it can be simplified: I might get back to this when I have more time in my hands. Also have a look at the answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305151/proving-that-cos2-pi-n-is-algebraic) question if you want to prove that $R_n$ is algebraic for every $n$.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Our internet went down for days.